# Array issue c# "cannot apply indexing"

Tags: c#, arrays

Potentially easy question here, I'm getting the error: `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Array'`

```
    public Array hello()
    {
        var damn = new[] { a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9};
        return damn;
    }
    private void a1disable()
    {

        var a = new[] { a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9 };
        var b = hello();

        a[1].Enabled = false;
        b[1].Enabled = false;
    }
```

`a[1].Enabled = false;` works absolutely fine! it's just `b[1].Enabled = false;` which throws the error i described above, i haven't used arrays much before so i'm sorry if the answer seems obvious, i'm just looking for clarification as to why this is happening.
Thanks in advance if you can help :)

Comment: I'm surprised the `hello()` method compiles as you are casting SomeClass[] to Array. Upvote for a question that has shown me something I didn't know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All arrays derive from `Array` but `Array` is not indexable. Only concrete arrays are indexable. Without knowing the element type that the array has it is impossible getting a value out of it in a strongly typed way.

Make `Hello` return an `int[]` or whatever the right element type is.

Answer (score 4):

`Array` class does not have any indexer, you have to use the `GetValue` method, suppose the type of each element in `b` is `TextBox`, try this:

```
((TextBox) b.GetValue(1)).Enabled = false;
```

If you know the type of all elements beforehand, such as `TextBox`, why not just use the type `TextBox[]` as the return type of your `hello()` method?

```
public TextBox[] hello(){
  //....
}
//Then you can keep the old code.
```

Comment: a1,a2 etc are actually textboxes, does this mean i can/should change 'Button' to 'Textbox'?

Comment: @LucasHolmes no, just replace `Button` with `TextBox`, that's just my suppose.

Answer (score 2):

`Array` is primarily a base class for for the system.  You [shouldn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) be using `Array` as the return here:

> The Array class is the base class for language implementations that
>   support arrays. However, only the system and compilers can derive
>   explicitly from the Array class. **Users should employ the array
>   constructs provided by the language.**

Change the return type to `whateverType[]`.

```
public whateverType[] hello()
{
    var damn = new[] { a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9};
    return damn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You make your syntax a little more simple by returning a generic instead of an array. In your case that would look like:

```
    public List<object> hello()
    {
        return new List<object> { a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9 };
    }
```

Just replace "object" with the appropriate type. The advantage these have is you can add/remove items later if necessary more easily than you could with an array. These also have expanded support for LINQ syntax. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using controls, then you can do:

```
public Control[] hello()
{
    return new Control[] { a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9};
}
```

This way you can access needed control properties, like `Enabled`.

I think it is even better to simplify it to a private field:

```
private Control[] _hello = new Control[] { a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9};
```

Or if you are intend to use it from outside, to a public auto-property:

```
public Control[] Hello {get; private set;}

    // init somewhere (to example, in the constructor)
    Hello = new Control[] { a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the function returning type `Array`, hello() in your example, and know a base type stored in the array, I use `int` in my example below. Then you can add a `using System.Linq;` and change:

```
var b = hello();
```

to

```
var b = hello().Cast<int>().ToArray();
```